# Подключение к базе данных mysql по локальной сети

Tags: mysql

Есть программа на Java, которая при запуске подключается к БД, которая хранится в musql workbench. Необходимо перенести эту программу на другой компьютер так, что там она тоже подключалась к локальной сети, но чтобы при этом экспортировать базу данных так, чтобы не нужно было заново ставить и настраивать workbench.

Comment: workbench это просто инструмент доступа к БД. Он работает сам по себе. И сервер MySQL, который собственно является держателем самой базы так же работает сам по себе и ему не требуется для работы наличие чего нибудь еще. И workbench ему совершенно не нужен

Comment: Спасибо, а можете подсказать, как создать этот сервер, ибо при экспорте БД сохраняется в формате SQL Text File

Comment: Собственно установить ПО сервера (сам сервер можно скачать без workbench), после чего запустить и утилитой mysql загрузить текстовый дамп.